# Drupal 8 newbie - How to access fields inside of page.html.twig?

Tags: drupal

#### {{ page.content.field_title.value }}

Is there anyway for me to access just the title field inside of my page.html.twig

Comment: Are you using module? Or just templates?

Comment: I'm just using the template. I think the answer i was given was good ! thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the title, any of the following should work

```
{{ node.label }}
  Or
{{  page[‘#title’]}}
```

But, I like the following

```
   {% if node.title.value %}
  <h1>{{ node.title.value }}</h1>
{% elseif page['#title'] %}
  <h1>{{ page['#title'] }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

From [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2015-11-03/print-title-in-pagehtmltwig-in-d8)